# Itunes Connect App Preview Disappearing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My app preview keeps disappearing after i tap save, or leave and come back again after a while. The app preview uploads without issues using safari, than it displays that it is processing after choosing the poster frame, i tap save sometimes its gone other times i have to check back later and than it is gone.
I thought this was just an issue with iTunes connect but my app got approved and still not video.

I've tried uploading 
Prores format and H.264, though i doubt this is the issue as it would display 'unable to load file'.

I am uploading it for the 5.5 inch and using that for the other devices.

Has anybody else ran into this issue? I searched around and got nothing.

**Update:** 
This stopped happening after a while, must have been a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using Safari. Wait for the **entire** preview to finish processing. Click Save. Edit Poster Frame. Click Save.

I've had the same issue and saving before it finishes processing, or trying to set the Poster Frame before it finishes processing will cause issues.

Also, make sure you're inline with the [App Preview Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html).

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it out.